# What is the purpose or meaning of the number after the widget object for Logcat output? For example, Spinner@4108d370

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

For a Logcat output, what is the meaning of the number? For example, 4108d370 after the view object like a spinner widget,  android.widget.Spinner@4108d370

Comment: That number is the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object, which is equivalent with `Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.